# SELECT /*!N SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `table` - What is this?

Tags: mysql

I just enabled mysql slow query logging.

Now I see these queries being logged on different tables time to time:

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `paitents`;
# Time: 181128  6:38:50
# User@Host: my_testdatabase[my_testdatabase] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.964142  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 1606915
```

I just searched and found out that it might be the database dump causing these queries.

But I want to make sure that its the mysql dump not some unauthorized access.

**This is the latest log from that specific table in my logs right now:**

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `paitents`;
# Time: 181128  6:38:50
# User@Host: my_testdatabase[my_testdatabase] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.964142  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 1606915
```

**And here is the logs of dumps that were created:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 381511206 Nov 23 23:21 my_testdatabase_2018-11-23.sql.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 381754145 Nov 24 23:21 my_testdatabase_2018-11-24.sql.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 381999764 Nov 25 23:21 my_testdatabase_2018-11-25.sql.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 382146325 Nov 26 23:22 my_testdatabase_2018-11-26.sql.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 382357755 Nov 27 23:23 my_testdatabase_2018-11-27.sql.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 382384209 Nov 28 06:29 my_testdatabase_2018-11-28.sql.tar.bz2
```

Now here I can see the difference in the latest query logged in slow query log and the latest dump created.

Latest query logged time: 181128  6:38:50
Latest dump created time: 2018-11-28 06:29

Why is there a difference?

Comment: The file could have been created at the beginning of the export process and that particular table could have been queried a few minutes later. This is not particularly suspicious. Btw, the slow query log will not really help in tracing external hacks, you need to inspect your webserver's log for that.

Comment: `SQL_NO_CACHE` instructs MySQL to by pass the cache when executing the query. It would otherwise fetch the result from cache (if it is present in the cache) making it execute faster than it normally would. This could be normal i.e. added by MySQL.

Comment: @Shadow Can you please give me an idea where i can find these webserver's logs?

Comment: It depends on the webserver, its settings, and on the operating system you use. If you do an Internet search with with the webserver's name, I'm pretty sure you can find guidance on this.